# Discord.py member roles list

Tags: sqlalchemy, discord.py

So my goal is to pull a list of roles for each member in a server and store them in a MYSQL database. on the backend for my bot. However when I try to pull the roles I get [none] as my list. So I know I am doing something wrong. I can't seem to solve it so I am asking for some pointers.

A bit of a preface I am using SQLalchemy with pymysql, and discord.py rewrite. Also this code is housed in a cog.

Her is the trouble code section

```
@tasks.loop(hours=24)
    # Runs every 24 hours to update tables
    async def update_24(self):
        print("Updating...")
        async for guild in self.client.fetch_guilds():
            Eng = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{self.sql_user}:{self.sql_passwd}@{self.sql_host}/{guild.id}',
                                echo=False)
            Engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{self.sql_user}:{self.sql_passwd}@{self.sql_host}/{self.sql_ddb}',
                                   echo=False)

            async for member in guild.fetch_members():
                member_id = member.id  # Integer
                displayName = member.display_name  # String
                discriminator = member.discriminator  # String
                mention = member.mention  # String
                server = guild.name  # String
                # update existing
                User = discord.Member
                _roles = member.roles # <== Trouble spot

                roles = str(_roles)
                print(f"Guild: {guild.name}, User: {member.name}, roles: {_roles}, {roles}")
                dm = str(User.dm_channel)
                dt = datetime.today()
                date = dt
                engine1 = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{self.sql_user}:{self.sql_passwd}@{self.sql_host}/{guild.id}',
                                        echo=False)
                with Session(engine1) as session:
                    usr = Users()

                    UserExists = session.query(Users).filter_by(UserID=member.id).first()
                    if not UserExists:
                        usr.UserID = member_id
                        usr.DisplayName = displayName.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
                        usr.Discriminator = discriminator.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
                        usr.Mention = mention.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
                        usr.DMChannel = dm.encode(encoding='UTF-8')

                        # TODO: needs fixed, stores as property object (needs to be string or list of actual names of roles)
                        usr.Roles = roles.encode(
                            encoding='UTF-8')

                        usr.Server = server.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
                        usr.LastUpdate = date
                        session.add(usr)
                        session.commit()
                        session.close()

                    else:
                        session.query(Users).filter_by(UserID=member.id).update({
                            "DisplayName": displayName.encode(encoding='UTF-8'),
                            "Discriminator": discriminator.encode(encoding='UTF-8'),
                            "Mention": mention.encode(encoding='UTF-8'),
                            "DMChannel": dm.encode(encoding='UTF-8'),
                            "Roles": roles.encode(encoding='UTF-8'),
                            "PostCount": 0,
                            "LastUpdate": date
                        }, synchronize_session="fetch")
                        session.commit()
                        session.close()
```

the output of the print statement i have to verify the list is:

```
Guild: Sinless Games Official Discord, User: Helix, roles: [None], [None]
Guild: Sinless Games Official Discord, User: Jessica Riley, roles: [None], [None]
Guild: Sinless Games Official Discord, User: Andrew Palermo, roles: [None], [None]
Guild: Sinless Games Official Discord, User: lilfizzle063, roles: [None], [None]
Guild: Sinless Games Official Discord, User: WidgetBot, roles: [None], [None]
```

How ever i have verified that Each member has roles. According to the documentation even the  @everyone role is default and will always appear first, but i get an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

So after many hours i managed to solve it my doinging something i thought would have been pointless.

Here is my solution for those who may need the help later on.

```
member: Member
            async for member in guild.fetch_members():
                member = await guild.fetch_member(member.id) # <== Fetches member object
                member_id = member.id  # Integer
                displayName = member.display_name  # String
                discriminator = member.discriminator  # String
                mention = member.mention  # String
                server = guild.name  # String
                # update existing
                User = Member
                _roles = []
                for role in member.roles:  # <== Iterates through each roll and adds them to a list
                    _roles.append(role.name) # adds to list
                roles = str(_roles) # makes the list to string for storage
                # print(f"Guild: {guild.name}, User: {member.name}, roles: {_roles}, {roles}")
                dm = str(User.dm_channel)
                dt = datetime.today()
                date = dt
                engine1 = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{self.sql_user}:{self.sql_passwd}@{self.sql_host}/{guild.id}',
                                        echo=False)
```